# Synapse post запрос

Tags: delphi

Собственно, как отправить пост запрос в `synapse`?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [моё дополнение Synapse.](http://arhangelsoft.ru/delphi/advanced-synapse-library-thttpsendex/) `THttpSendEx` станет так же легко использовать как и `TIdHTTP` от `Indy`. Даже `GZIP` поддерживает.